# Populating quick search bar with VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have run into a bit of an obstacle while trying to automate a process we have here at work.
Basically, I'm trying to get VBA to launch Internet Explorer, login into a page (page that opens is web-based SAP), and then to populate a quick search bar with a T-Code and execute it.

Now, my knowledge of VBA is definitely not something I'd consider my strongest game, however I did manage to get past the login page and open the next screen where I'm supposed to populate to quick search bar. The problem is that I can't seem to lock onto the text box I need to populate. The reason for this is (I presume) because it is JavaScript (while the login screen is pure HTML). Below, I've pasted the code I'm currently using and a portion from the page I'm working on.
How can I resolve this?

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "www.pageimtryingtoresolve.com"
'loads webpage

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
'waits for login webpage to load fully

IE.document.getelementbyid("userid").Value = "username"
IE.document.getelementbyid("password").Value = "hunter2"
IE.document.getelementbyid("submit").Click
'above enters GPID, Password and Clicks on the login button


Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.READYSTATE = 4
'again waits for webpage to load fully but this time it's sap 
opening

IE.document.getelementbyid("qstext").Value = "ZSE16 - ECC"

End Sub
```

Below are parts of the source of the page which I think are relevant. Keep in mind that the the ID of the text box is "qstext".

```
function quickSearch(event){var qc=document.getElementById("qstext");
if(qc.value.length==0&&document.getElementById("completeDiv")) 
{hideCompleteDiv();}  

tltd=createtd(options);tltr.appendChild(tltd);tltbody.appendChild(tltr);
tltr=document.createElement("tr");var 
qslabel=createLabel(QUICKSEARCH,'Arial,Helvetica,sansserif');
tltd=createtd(qslabel);tltr.appendChild(tltd);var 
qstext=document.createElement('input');qstext.type='text';
qstext.id='qstext';qstext.style.width='403';qstext.onkeyup=function()
{var e=arguments[0]||event;quickSearch(e);};tltd=createtd(qstext);
tltd.colSpan='2';tltr.appendChild(tltd);tltd.appendChild
(document.createElement("td"));tltr.appendChild(tltd);   
if(refreshflag.indexOf('true') !== -1)
```

Comment: So, there is no url to reproduce the issue!!! I wonder why most of the web-scraping questions are asked within vba tag where there is hardly any url to play with!!!

Comment: There is no point in me giving out the URL since it's behind login. I can paste the full source from that page, if it's of any benefit.